# How to change the position of a data modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a data model in my blade.Once the 'Send Request'buttonis clicked the pop up form should appear.Of course it appears,but not in the expected way.It should appear in the center of the window.But it's not.If appears in the left and only the part of it can be seen.Can anyone help me to sort this out???

The code in the blade is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id={{'E'.$result->id}} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog model">
<div class="modal-content" >
  <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Send Request for Editing
        </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="text-align: center"><b>{{ $result->school_name }} </b></div>
      @if($result->Edittable == 'Requested')
          <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="text-align: center"><b>This School has been already Requested for Editing. Please Proceed only if this is your first request</b></div>
      @endif


      <form method="post" action="{{ url('school_edit_request') }}">

          <!--
           @if( $msg_typ != NULL )

              @if($msg_typ == 'Success')
                      <strong>{{$msg}}</strong>
                  </div>
              @elseif($msg_typ == 'Failed')
                  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="text-align: center" >
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                     <strong>{{$msg}}</strong>
                  </div>
              @endif
           @endif -->

          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="School_Id" value="{{ $result->id }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="Request_By" value="{{  Auth::user()->id }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="Request_Date" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="Status" value="Pending">

          <br />
          <label class="control-label" >Reason For Editing</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="Reason" >
              <option>Incorrect School Details </option>
              <option>Incorrect Principal Details </option>
              <option>Change in teacher in charge</option>
              <option>Change in No, of traffic controllers</option>

          </select>
          <br />
          <label class="control-label" >Request Priority</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="Priority" >
              <option>High</option>
              <option>Medium</option>
              <option>Low</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <label class="control-label" >Additional Note</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="Note" required="required" data-parsley-error-message="Please Enter At least One line of Description "></textarea>
          <br />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Send Request</button>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have it live?

Answer (score 1):

Following will fix the problem and bring back the modal in center

Add `class="modalcenter"` in HTML

```
<div class="modal modalcenter fade" id={{'E'.$result->id}} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Add following CSS in style sheet, using `!important` rule to make sure that what ever pushing the modal to left will be overridden with `modalcenter` selector properties.

```
.modalcenter {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(5%) !important;
}
```

SideNote: you can adjust the position of modal on screen

- (Between Left to Right) by setting value of `translateX(0%)` positive e.g `5%` will push it to right
- (Between Right to Left) by setting value of `translateX(0%)` negative e.g `-5%` will push it to left
- (Between Top to Bottom) by adjusting value of `translateY(0%)` positive e.g `5%` will push it towards bottom
- (Between Bottom to Top) by adjusting value of `translateY(0%)` negative e.g `-5%` will pull it towards top